# How do I create an array of every key in a generic type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Say I have declared a type:

```
type MyCustomType = {
    key1: 'value1' | 'value2'
    key2: boolean
    key3: number
}
```

I am trying to write some code that will check if all values for a given object of type "MyCustomType" have defined values.
e.g.

```
function validate(input: MyCustomType): boolean {
    const fieldsToCheck = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] as const;
    return fieldsToCheck.every((key) => !!input[key])
}
```

I can manually define 'fieldsToCheck' like the example, but ideally I would like a way to generate the array from the type definition.  Conversely I would be okay with declaring the array, then defining the type relative to that array.

what do?

Comment: You can't generate values from types, as the type system in TypeScript is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).  You can generate a type from a value, although this will just give you key types and not the full object type.  You can maybe make a dummy object and then derive both `MyCustomType` and `fieldsToCheck` from it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDkeRw).  Does that meet your needs? Or am I missing something?

Comment: honestly it almost meets my needs and is a fun creative answer.  The one gotcha for my specific scenario is that key1: string is actually not a string, but a union of a few specific string values.

Comment: Well, `key1: string` is what’s in the question.  If you have an unmet need then you might want to [edit] the question to specify it.

Comment: I see you edited the question (but without "@jcalz" mentioning me I don't get notified of such things).  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdoEvw) work for you?  It's getting sillier.  Personally I'd probably just do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7O5qN) where you have to maintain redundant info but you get a warning if you make a mistake.  Let me know which, if any, of these approaches you want me to write up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const fieldsToCheck = Object.keys(input);
```

This will return a `string[]` of the keys from your input object